# bibliography reference to clifford algebras

Tags: reference-request, clifford-algebras

I am starting to study Clifford algebras and geometric calculus. I am not finding references for these topics.
Someone could point me a reference for these topics?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A straightforward Internet search, or at least a glance at English Wikipedia, turns up dozens of references. It does not sound like you looked.

Answer (score 0):

There are some resources on the web. 
You can start for example here:

https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/l.dorst/clifford/

http://www.geometricalgebra.net/

http://www.itpa.lt/~acus/Knygos/Clifford_algebra_books/Dorst_Lasenby_Guide_to_Geometric_Algebra_in_Practice.pdf